# Is there a way to show pdf in its original structure in the human review custom entity labelling in aws sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-textract, amazon-comprehend

I have modified [this sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-comprehend-a2i) to read PDFs in tabular format. I would like to keep the tabular structure of the original pdf when doing the human review process. I notice the custom worker task template uses the crowd-entity-annotation element which seems to read only texts. I am aware that the human reviewer process reads from an S3 key which contains raw text written by the textract process.

I have been considering writing to S3 using tabulate but I don't think that is the best solution. I would like to keep the structure and still have the ability to annotate custom entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprehend now natively support to detect custom-defined entities for pdf documents. To do so, you can try the following steps:

1. Follow this [github readme](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-comprehend-semi-structured-documents-annotation-tools) to start the annotation process for PDF documents.
2. Once the annotations are produced. You can use Comprehend CreateEntityRecognizer API to train a custom entity model for Semi-structured document”
3. Once entity recognizer is trained, you can use StartEntitiesDetectionJob API to run inference for PDF documents

Comment: "Follow this github readme". Which one?

Comment: Apologize: here is the link to github repo - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-comprehend-semi-structured-documents-annotation-tools